# no instance of constructor "AcademicStaff::AcademicStaff" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, intellisense

I declared

```
AcademicStaff(int, char *, char *, int , char *, char *,int, char *,char *)
```

constructor for initiliazing.

When I called the functiion in main I got an error

```
 "  2   IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "AcademicStaff::AcademicStaff" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (int, char, char, int, char, char, int, char, char)".
```

Calling Function :

```
AcademicStaff headOdDepartment(staffID, *firstName, *lastName, telNo, *address, *email, annualSalary, *title, *status);
myDepartment.setheadOfDepartment(headOdDepartment);
```

Comment: I'm going to *guess* `firstName, lastName, address, email, title`, and `status`, are all `char*`. So what possessed you to dereference them on the invoke of that constructor?

Comment: Well yeah. You're passing it the arguments `(int, char, char, int, char, char, int, char, char)` which aren't the same as `(int, char *, char *, int, char *, char *, int, char *, char *)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function with `AcademicStaff headOdDepartment(staffID, firstName, lastName, telNo, address, email, annualSalary, title, status);`
You're sending the first element if you send `*charArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor accepts pointers to strings. See below

```
AcademicStaff(int, char *, char *, int , char *, char *,int, char *,char *)
```

but when you are calling constructor you are dereferencing the pointers using * e.g *firstName. See

```
AcademicStaff headOdDepartment(staffID, *firstName, *lastName, telNo, *address, *email, annualSalary, *title, *status);
```

Remove the dereferencing and use the following code

```
AcademicStaff headOdDepartment(staffID, firstName, lastName, telNo, address, email, annualSalary, title, status);
```