# fraction operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, fractions

I am new in C++ and I have a problem with operator overloading. I just implemented the functions in header file.I want to add two fractional numbers simplest form to each other.I implemented a gcd for simplification and implemented operator + for addinf the together bu I got an error for the part in operator+.Error is in fraction add(f1.getNum1()) f1 is highligted : "no instance of construction (fraction::fraction) matching the argumentlist, types are(int,int)"
Here is the code:

```
a& operator+=(const a& f1,const a& f2){
    a add(f1.getNum1()*f2.getDen2()+f2.getNum2()*f1.getDen1(),f1.getDen1()*f2.getDen2());
    return add;
}

#endif
```

I have another problem in the main.cpp code**no operator "<<" matches these operands operand** .I initiliazee the constructor.Now ı want to add to fractional numbers.But I get a n error for  cout "<<" in the left side of result :                                                                      `result=fractional1+fractional2;                                                                              cout << num1 <<"/"<< den1 <<"+"<<num2<<"/"<< den2 <<" = "<<result <<endl;`

Comment: Your `fraction(int num1, int num2, int den1, int den2)` function uses the value of `this->num1`, `this->num2`, `this->den2`, and `this->den2` before setting them.

Comment: dup? :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/30000121/86967 -- passing the wrong arguments to a constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `operator+=`, you declare a fraction:

```
fraction add(f1.getNum1()*f2.getDen2()+f2.getNum2()*f1.getDen1(),f1.getDen1()*f2.getDen2());
```

This is of the form:

```
fraction a(int1, int2);
```

But you have not defined any constructor for `fraction` that takes two `int` arguments. The compiler tells you (correctly) that it doesn't know what you mean.

Comment: Can you check the code again,please?.I have another problem :(     I attached it at the end of the code

Comment: @emre: You are trying to do two things at once: add two fractions, and send a fraction to `cout` using the insertion operator (`<<`). **Also you neglected to write an insertion operator for `fraction`.** Develop new functionality in isolation whenever you can.